# Displaying only specified roles based on session role

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently I have a tab where I'm displaying all the roles of a person which is fetching them from my database. Now I've added an extra column in the database name can_manage. This column basically shows what role a specific person can control, for example a digital director will be able to control the digital team. Currently my database looks like this:

[image]

Now by default I'm showing all my records from database in View class:

```
<?php if($roles) foreach($roles as $key => $role):?>
              <a data-filter=".roles<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $role ?></a>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Model Class:

```
function get_roles_idpair()
    {
        $idpair=array();
        $this->db->from("crm_client_roles");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row):
            $idpair[$row['roles_id']]=$row['role'];
        endforeach;
        return $idpair;
    }
```

Now everytime a user logs in they are assigned a roles_id from the database. Now I want it so that  suppose the digital director logs in, he can only be able to see the people assigned to them in the can_manage part and their own role. And all the people with 0 as can_manage can only see the role that they currently are.

Comment: So what is the problem you have?

Comment: I want to be able to show only the people assigned to a person in the can_manage part and their own role. And if the can_manage is 0, it should only show their role

Comment: Also, you might want to consider moving the `can_manage` relationship to a different table so that your role implementation can support a single role managing multiple groups of people. E.G the `Admin` role being able to manage `Sales Director`s and `Digital Director`s.